# Collada file not show clear in scenekit

Tags: swift, blender, scenekit

1. i have imported my collada file of a 3d tunnel in xcode.

2.when i run my sample project it shows 3d tunnel very far and small

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/tube.dae")!

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
```

3. i just import my collada 3d object in xcode default ship code what should i do to see my 3d tunnel near to the scene as in following pics
   in Blender:

[image: 3d tunnel in blender]

4. when i run SceneKit project the tunnel in simulator looks like this:

[[image: 3d tunnel in scenekit][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UY1O.jpg)

5.How can i get my 3d tunnel same view in scenekit as it is in blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Collada file already have a camera in it, i.e. the one you're using to produce the first rendering?

If so, locate that camera/node (childNodeWithName). Assign it as your view's point of view. Don't create a new camera in your code.

Or, if you really need to create a new camera, put it at the same location as the point of view used for the first rendering.

Comment: yes i have camera in it but i want to use a new camera can you please suggest with an example code sorry i not getting the point you recommended....

Comment: Your SceneKit camera appears to be in the wrong place. Put it in the same spot as your Blender camera was.

Comment: That's great! Instead of a "thank you" comment, mark the answer as Accepted.